# How to avoid saving truncated data from JPA entity

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to save a bunch of data from two different entities named auditor_stamp_duty_report and deed_of assignment. These 2 entities share a one to one and join table relationship. When I try to persist data from postman using the post method, only data from one entity gets saved into the database. The data for the other entity gets truncated.

Here is my entity classes;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="auditor_stamp_duty_report")
public class AuditorStampDutyReport implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_of_tax_payer_organization", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Organization organization;

    @Column(name = "tin_of_tax_payer_organization")
    private Long tin_of_tax_payer_organization;

    @Column(name = "period_covered")
    private String period_covered;

    @Column(name = "date_of_transaction")
    private LocalDate date_of_transaction;

    @JoinColumn(name = "duty_payer")
    private String duty_payer;

    @Column(name = "tin_of_duty_payer")
    private Long tin_of_duty_payer;

    @Column(name = "address_of_duty_payer")
    private String address_of_duty_payer;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "instrument_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Instruments instruments;

    @Column(name = "assessment_number")
    private Long assessment_number;

    @Column(name = "receipt_number")
    private String receipt_number;

    @Column(name = "consideration")
    private Double consideration;

    @Column(name = "rate")
    private Double rate;

    @Column(name = "amount_payable")
    private Double amount_payable;

    @Column(name = "amount_paid")
    private Double amount_paid;

    @Column(name = "balance")
    private Double balance;

    @Column(name = "penalty")
    private Double penalty;

    @Column(name = "outstanding")
    private Double outstanding;

    @Column(name = "remarks")
    private String remarks;

    @Column(name="amount_recoverable")
    private Double amount_recoverable;

    @Column(name="date_of_payment")
    private LocalDate date_of_payment;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_profile_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserProfile userProfile;


        @OneToOne
        @JoinTable(
                name="auditor_stamp_duty_report_deed_of_assignment",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="auditor_stamp_duty_report_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="deed_of_assignment_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        )
        private DeedOfAssignment deed_of_assignment_id;

}



//second entity


package com.oasis.firsbacklogbackend.entity;

import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "deed_of_assignment")
public class DeedOfAssignment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="state_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private State state;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="lga_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Lga lga;

    @Column(name="ward")
    private Long ward;

    @Column(name="description_of_location")
    private String description_of_location;
}
```

also look at my dto layer which I am using to transfer data for bith entities below:

```
import lombok.Data;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Data
public class AuditorStampDutyReportDto {

    private  Long id;

    private Long id_of_tax_payer_organization;

    private String duty_payer;

    private Long tin_of_tax_payer_organization;

    private String period_covered;

    private LocalDate date_of_transaction;

    private Long tin_of_duty_payer;

    private String address_of_duty_payer;

    private Long instrument_id;

    private Long assessment_number;

    private String receipt_number;

    private Double consideration;

    private Double rate;

    private Double amount_payable;

    private Double amount_paid;

    private Double balance;

    private Double penalty;

    private LocalDate date_of_payment;

    private Double amount_recoverable;

    private Double outstanding;

    private String remarks;

    private Long user_profile_id;

    private Long deed_of_assignment_id;

    private Long state_id;

    private Long lga_id;

    private Long ward;

    private String description_of_location;
}
```

here is the service

```
@Data
@Service
public class AuditorStampDutyReportService {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuditorStampDutyReportService.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private BanksRepository banksRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AuditorStampDutyReportRepository auditorStampDutyReportRepository;

    @Autowired
    private OrganizationRepository organizationRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LgaRepository lgaRepository;

    @Autowired
    private StateRepository stateRepository;

    @Autowired
    private InstrumentsRepository instrumentsRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DeedOfAssignmentRepository deedOfAssignmentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;

    public AuditorStampDutyReport dtoToEntity (AuditorStampDutyReportDto dto){
        AuditorStampDutyReport report = new AuditorStampDutyReport();

        report.setId(dto.getId());
        Organization organization = organizationRepository.findById(dto.getId_of_tax_payer_organization()).orElse(null);
        report.setOrganization(organization);

        report.setTin_of_tax_payer_organization(dto.getTin_of_tax_payer_organization());
        report.setDate_of_transaction(dto.getDate_of_transaction());
        report.setPeriod_covered(dto.getPeriod_covered());

        report.setDuty_payer(dto.getDuty_payer());
        report.setTin_of_duty_payer(dto.getTin_of_duty_payer());
        report.setAddress_of_duty_payer(dto.getAddress_of_duty_payer());

        Instruments instruments = instrumentsRepository.findById(dto.getInstrument_id()).orElse(null);
        report.setInstruments(instruments);

        report.setAssessment_number(dto.getAssessment_number());
        report.setReceipt_number(dto.getReceipt_number());
        report.setConsideration(dto.getConsideration());
        report.setRate(dto.getRate());
        report.setAmount_payable(dto.getAmount_payable());
        report.setAmount_paid(dto.getAmount_paid());
        report.setBalance(dto.getBalance());
        report.setPenalty(dto.getPenalty());
        report.setDate_of_payment(dto.getDate_of_payment());
        report.setAmount_recoverable(dto.getAmount_recoverable());
        report.setOutstanding(dto.getOutstanding());
        report.setRemarks(dto.getRemarks());

        UserProfile userProfile = userProfileRepository.findById(dto.getUser_profile_id()).orElse(null);
        report.setUserProfile(userProfile);

        //why is deed of assignment is not getting saved into database?

//        DeedOfAssignment deedOfAssignment= null;
        if(dto.getDeed_of_assignment_id()!=null && dto.getDeed_of_assignment_id() > 0) {
            DeedOfAssignment deedOfAssignment = deedOfAssignmentRepository.findById(dto.getDeed_of_assignment_id()).orElse(null);
            if (deedOfAssignment != null) {
                report.setDeed_of_assignment_id(deedOfAssignment);
                State state = stateRepository.findById(dto.getState_id()).orElse(null);
                deedOfAssignment.setState(state);
                Lga lga = lgaRepository.findById(dto.getLga_id()).orElse(null);
                deedOfAssignment.setLga(lga);
                deedOfAssignment.setWard(dto.getWard());
                deedOfAssignment.setDescription_of_location(dto.getDescription_of_location());
            }
        }
        report= auditorStampDutyReportRepository.save(report);
        return report;
    }
```

data truncation

```
{
//gets into the auditor_stamp_duty-report table successfully
        "id_of_tax_payer_organization": 1,
        "id_of_duty_payer_or_bank": 29,
        "tin_of_tax_payer_organization": 3329644,
        "period_covered": "July 2017 to May 2010",
        "date_of_transaction": "2020-11-29",
        "tin_of_duty_payer_or_bank": 382890,
        "address_of_duty_payer_or_bank": "15, IBB close, Aso Drive, Fct, Abuja",
        "instrument_id": 13,
        "assessment_number": 219,
        "receipt_number": "cc92384",
        "consideration": 19470.0,
        "rate": 16.0,
        "amount_payable": 22000,
        "amount_paid": 280000,
        "balance": 2999000.0,
        "penalty": 398290.0,
        "outstanding": 7800.0,
        "remarks": "Are no longer in operation.",
        "user_profile_id": 1,
       
//does not get into the deed_of_assignment table successfully

        "deed_of_assignment_id": 6,
        "state_id": 20,
        "lga_id": 230,
        "ward": 12,
        "description_of_location": "A brown bungalow"

        }
```

I would appreciate your help

Comment: Since you have one to one relation between 2 entities using Join Table you should have used these annotations in DeedOfAssignment entity:
`@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="DeedOfAssignment_AuditorStampDutyReport", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="DeedOfAssignment_Id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="AuditorStampDutyReport_Id"))
private AuditorStampDutyReport account;`

Comment: @SkillsIndexOutOfBounds after trying this, the code is not working, am getting error ""org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!" I have refactored the code back to when it was working but still getting the error...

Comment: You are using @oneToOne mapping on AuditorStampDutyReport entity so you don't have to use the same annotation on DeedOfAssignment entity. You are missing cascade on  AuditorStampDutyReport `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` try adding this it should work. Also put this `report.setDeed_of_assignment_id(deedOfAssignment);` after setting all the fields of `deedOfAssignment`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by modifying the logic of my service layer in line with the requirements of my project. Here is the code snippet for my service below:

```
        if (instruments != null && instruments.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Deed of Assignment")) {

            DeedOfAssignment deedOfAssignment = new DeedOfAssignment();
            report.setDeedOfAssignmentId(deedOfAssignment);
            State state = stateRepository.findById(dto.getStateId()).orElse(null);
            deedOfAssignment.setState(state);
            if (state != null) {
                Lga lga = lgaRepository.findById(dto.getLgaId()).orElse(null);
                deedOfAssignment.setLga(lga);
            }
            deedOfAssignment.setWard(dto.getWard());
            deedOfAssignment.setDescriptionOfLocation(dto.getDescriptionOfLocation());
        }
```

I also added (cascade=CascadeType.ALL) to my oneToOne entity mapping like this:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name="auditor_stamp_duty_report_deed_of_assignment",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="auditor_stamp_duty_report_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="deed_of_assignment_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private DeedOfAssignment deedOfAssignmentId;
```

and it worked, saving the persisted data into the two tables/entities and producing the desired result without truncating the data.